# How to I can compile the Linux Kernel with GRSecurity and SELinux using the git repositories?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, grsecurity

I want compile the Linux kernel with two patches (Grsecurity and SELinux) using the git repositories if theses sources, my problem is in the patch file generation because I unknow how make the patches files of Grsecurity and SELinux to the main Linux Kernel.

I had tried to generate the grsecurity patch with the command in the branch 4.9 of the grsecurity github repository:

```
git format-patch -1 --abbrev=12 -o <OUTPUT_DIR> <The last commit named with "Linux 4.9.9">
```

but this not had made a rigth patch file.

The Kernel versions what I can make is the 4.9.x, 4.8.x and 4.10.x.